# addTab in adminhtml_sales_order_view: "Invalid Blocktype: Mage_..."

Tags: php, magento

**Edit:** Additionally to the code below, I have also tried to do exactly what this tutorial tells: http://www.magentothemess.com/archives/1267
Magento still wants to call a block, which name begins with "Mage_" :(

**Original Post**

I've tried so many tutorials, but Magento is still saying the same:

> Invalid Blocktype: Mage_AdminModifications_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_View_Tab_Custom.php

**What I've done?**

code/local/MyNamespace/AdminModifications/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <MyNamespace_AdminModifications>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </MyNamespace_AdminModifications>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <blocks>
      <MyNamespace_AdminModifications>
        <class>MyNamespace_AdminModifications_Block</class>
      </MyNamespace_AdminModifications>
    </blocks>
    <models>
        <MyNamespace_AdminModifications>
            <class>MyNamespace_AdminModifications_Model</class>
        </MyNamespace_AdminModifications>
    </models>
  </global>
  <adminhtml>
    <layout>
      <updates>
          <MyNamespace_AdminModifications>
              <file>adminmodifications.xml</file>
          </MyNamespace_AdminModifications>
      </updates>
    </layout>
  </adminhtml>
</config>
```

design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/adminmodifications.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <adminhtml_sales_order_view>
        <reference name="sales_order_tabs">
            <action method="addTab">
                <name>order_custom</name>
                <block>AdminModifications/adminhtml_sales_order_view_tab_custom</block>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_sales_order_view>
</layout>
```

code/local/MyNamespace/AdminModifications/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/View/Tab/Custom.php

```
<?php
class MyNamespace_AdminModifications_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_View_Tab_Custom
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template
    implements Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface
{
    protected $_chat = null;

    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setTemplate('custom/tab.phtml');
    }

    public function getTabLabel() {
        return $this->__('Custom Tab');
    }

    public function getTabTitle() {
        return $this->__('Custom Overview');
    }

    public function canShowTab() {
        return true;
    }

    public function isHidden() {
        return false;
    }

    public function getOrder(){
        return Mage::registry('current_order');
    }
```

design/adminhtml/default/default/template/custom/tab.phtml (jus copied from somewhere for testing)

```
<?php
/**
 * Custom tab template
 */
?>
<div class="input-field">
 <label for="custom_field">Custom Field</label>
 <input type="text" class="input-text" name="custom_field" id="custom_field" />
</div>
```

Where is my mistake hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AdminModifications -> **MyNamespace_**AdminModifications

```
        <action method="addTab">
            <name>order_custom</name>
            <block>MyNamespace_AdminModifications/adminhtml_sales_order_view_tab_custom</block>
        </action>
```

because

```
<blocks>
  <MyNamespace_AdminModifications>
    <class>MyNamespace_AdminModifications_Block</class>
  </MyNamespace_AdminModifications>
</blocks>
```

Tip for the future: if you ever see magento trying to load **Mage_*** class instead of your class - 99% that you have an error in your **config.xml** file or typo in calling a block/model/helper by config name (like `<MyNamespace_AdminModifications>` in this case)

Comment: Thank you so much! I felt that I have tried all possible combinations already. Seems that I missed that one and just tried instead the module name and the namespace name separately. You really saved my day. (And thanks for the useful tip for the future)